# can the below c++ thread code cause a process crash on an embedded system?

Tags: c++, pthreads

similar c++ code as below is written for an embedded device. the process running on the device crashes upon start. on some other version of the device, crash is not observed. can it be related to the thread argument & thread detach being called. on normal linux desktop environment it does not crash. can anyone pls give their comments. 
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


#define NUM_THREADS     2

void *PrintHello(void *msg)
{
    cout<<(char*)msg<<endl;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Hello World! It's me, thread !\n");
        sleep(2);
    }
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    const char* ch = "hello how r u.i'm passing argument";
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)ch);
        pthread_detach(threads[t]);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whay happens in your embedded OS when main() exits?  I never let main() exit and usually use it for some functionality that needs a large stack, (eg. SD-card handler and file system).  Then again - I have not used pthreads on an embedded system.  Might be interesting to try preventing main() from exiting, just as a test, eg. by hanging it on an infinite sleep(), or whatever.  Also note the @Tomalak answer - you should link in thread-safe versions of your libs, if you have that choice, or lock up printf() with a mutex.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

The C++ standard library, by default, is not thread-safe... stream objects like `cout` in particular.

It may or may not have anything to do with the system being embedded. It's possible that the standard library implementation for the desktop system is more thread-safe, or it just happens to be implemented slightly differently, or perhaps you just got [un]lucky that you did not observe any undesired behaviour when testing on the desktop.